# Should I use index.html or index.php on my website?

Tags: php, html

I have created a website and have been hosting it for a while, but I created a contact form under the directory `/contact/ (under public_html)` with the file `index.php` so it can send php mail.

My homepage of my website is named `index.html` under my root directory.
Should I change my homepage to `index.php` (even though it includes no php on the page)?

Or is it okay to keep some directories `index.php` and some `index.html`?

Comment: You can do whatever you want. It's probably easier to remember if you're consistent.

Comment: I prefer using `.php` even for pages that don't contain any. But it comes down to personal preference.

Comment: Obidian Age -Yeah, i'm going to do that on my website because then it hides what pages use my server and what doesn't, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no real benefit to using .php over .html for small static webpages. A .html page may be slightly faster due to the fact that it is not sent to the PHP parser first. However, that speed would be negligible so isn't really worth mentioning.

One reason you may want to use a .php file is if you modularize your site. For example, you may want your header code in one php file, your navigation in another, and your footer in yet another. That way you can use php to include the code from each of your module files and include them on every page in your site.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep either of the file types if you want.

But if there are both **index.php** and **index.html**, index.html will always be used by the server instead of index.php.

Answer (score 0):

be welcome
as far as i know, there is no major problem using `index.html` over `index.php`, the only thing you should consider is that one has priority over the other, `*.html` is static and whenever you have two with the same name but different extension(*.html, *.php) the other will be ignored. Also, it's often used to help people when they want to prevent users from seeing your web directory files structure by default or in case when your server is facing issues with routes and internal configuration, by redirecting(using a php with redirection instructions) or html with not allowed access text within.

If you're considering implementing some extra processing features or server redirect you can `*.php`, if it's just a maintenance page or a static website you can go with `.html`.

In modern frameworks when you see a `index.php` it means it will be the only page used, always, the others will be requested within it's context.

I'm bit out of date about these things but i think it's, also you can check google for a quick check in case i missed things or have explained it wrong.